# Windows are unresponsive for a few seconds after boot (probably IO error with HDD)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, io

When Windows is loaded and I am logged in into my desktop, the system gets unresponsive for about 10-15 seconds. During this time, the HDD led indicator at the case is either flashing or on (solid).

I suspect that it's the 1.5TB HDD (which might has some bad sectors), because Windows is on a 60GB SSD (so programs go to the HDD).

I thought that I count try to identify which process or processes have the problem, then block the startup of this program or check what other options I have. How can I do this? It would be good to be able to request from the app to:

- Startup with windows
- create a log file.

System info:

> CPU: i7@3.00GHz
>
> RAM: 6GB@1600MHz
>
> SSD: OCZ Agility 3 (60GB)
>
> HDD: WD Green 1,5TB (SATA II)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use `MSCONFIG`

Click the start button and type msconfig

Then a Window will open, select the start up tab.

Here you can chose what starts with your machine (and what doesn't) by simply checking/unchecking.

Do read up on this first in case you un-check something you shouldn't.

When you're done, you can restart the machine to see it load (hopefully) quicker.

[image]

So, you need to pretty much disable everything. If the problem has gone, then bring in the programs one at a time until you find the one with the issue!

Also, often these things are caused by tasks within Task Scheduler.

It could also be the AV (if you have one)

Comment: I know how to disable programs from startup. What I want to find out is what program causes the IO lag which entails my system being unresponsive.

Comment: Re-enable one program at a time and see if it happens

Comment: @chipperyman573 and Dave Rook: I've disabled them all as you've said and the problem persists (sorry for the delayed reply).

Comment: @Chris, in that case, download a SMART tool (acronis is good and free) and see if that shines any light on the hard drive condition. Failing that, it could be hardware so you may need to disable hard ware bit by bit, but start with SMART tool