# Is there any way to check the Disk I/O that happens after startup and the duration for each task?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, freeze, boot

I am trying to troubleshoot a hard freeze of my computer (Windows 7) after startup.
After 3-4 seconds after the user login screen, the OS freezes:

- Pressing the Windows button at the keyboard doesn't do anything
- Using the mouse for selecting an area at the desktop doesn't work
- **But** the mouse movement works just fine

The OS is located on an SSD drive (OCZ Agility 3 (60GB)) and "My Documents" folder and index location have been transfered to another disk.
I've tried disabling all the startup processes using msconfing, but the freezing still occured.

While the freezing happens the HDD led on the case is blinking, so I am thinking it could be an I/O problem.

Is there any way to see the tasks that perform I/O after startup and the duration of each one?

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/639221/windows-are-unresponsive-for-a-few-seconds-after-boot-probably-io-error-with-hd) is my earlier question. I've created this one, because I am asking for a specific question different than the one I've posted before.

Thank you

**Edit:**
This is what I've done so far:

1. Changed Dropbox location from an older HDD to a newer 3TB 7200RPM Seagate Baracuda
2. Changed the location of the Index of Windows to the newer HDD (as above)

Still, there is a lag at start (**now even the pointer presents a lag**).
I've uploaded a screenshot from Process Monitor *that filters all entries with Duration bigger than 1"*, as you can see, the PC started at 11:35:53. Is this the time after the user sign in screen?

Now, the lag lasts about 10-20 seconds max and there are a lot of entries from the `SearchIndexer.exe`.

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Sysinternals Process Monitor will probably be your best bet.  You can enable boot time logging and view the processes that start.  You can then filter your view to only show File System activity (or you can tweak as needed).

I would also recommend adding the relative time column so you can find gaps/pauses to see if that helps you identify any problems.

Here are some resources for this:

http://www.msigeek.com/6231

http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2012/07/02/3506849.aspx

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this great tool! :) I've edited my question with some more info.

Answer (score 1):

The windows assessment and deployment kit has a tool to troubleshhot slow startups

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848076(v=vs.85).aspx